# Converting string to byte array in C# (CSV)

Tags: c#, .net, string, arrays, split

I wrote a function to convert `byte[]` to `string`, and I add ";" after each byte. Now I want to convert this `string` to `byte[]` by splitting the string (similar to a CSV string).

```
public string ByteArrayToString(byte[] byteArray,string s)
{       
    for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
    {
        s += byteArray[i].ToString() + ";";
    }
    s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1);
    return s;
}
```

How could I write a function to convert this string to that byte array again?

Comment: Is the string like `T;*;|;m;` or `84;42;124;109;`?

Comment: "thanks BUT it couldn't help me! i want to split my string by ";" then put it in the array then convert it to byte [] " try to write some pseudo code for this so we can see what you want. My understading of that qoute is you want to cast a string[] to a byte[] while interpreting the string values as a byte each. Which is not possible. You need to convert each value

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
var byteArray = new byte[] {123, 11, 111};
var stringBytes = string.Join(";", byteArray.Select(b => b.ToString()));
var newByteArray = stringBytes.Split(';').Select(s => byte.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you want to get rid of the `;` when converting also. I think you want to do something like this:

```
byte[] result = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s.Replace(";",""));
```

This will fail if the original byte array actually contains a `;`that is valid data, but in that case you will have lots of problems anyway since your "CSV" file will be wrongly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Split String](http://dotnetperls.com/string-split)

Comment: thanks BUT it couldn't help me! i want to split my string by ";" then put it in the array then convert it to byte []

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder` will be useful instead of `String` (Performance wise).

With `StringBuilder`:

```
byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(objStringBuilder.ToString());
```

with `String`:

```
byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(objString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.Split(new char[]{';'}, 
          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => byte.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks BUT it couldn't help me! i want to split my string by ";" then put it in the array then convert it to byte []

Comment: Try this: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str.Replace(";", string.Empty);`

Comment: wont work  byteArray[i].ToString() + ";" does not concatenate the byte values as char but uses 1-3 char pr. byte

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
return encoding.GetBytes(yourStringVariable);
```

Comment: the values are "printed" some 32 is "32" not " " as your code expects

Answer (score 0):

I know you already know the answer by now... but this code solves the problem, i hope it helps someone else.

```
        int counter= 0;
        string cadena = "8,5,6,3,4,6,3"
        string[] foto = cadena.Split(',');
        byte[] fotoFinal = new byte[foto.Length];
        foreach (string s in foto)
        {
            fotoFinal[contador] = Convert.ToByte(s);
            counter++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply :)

```
public static byte[] Bytes ( this string Key )
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, Key.Binary().Length / 8 )
                     .Select(Index => Convert.ToByte(
                         Key.Binary().Substring(Index * 8, 8), 2))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] sbytes   = sl.Split(',');
                    byte[] b          = new byte[sbytes.Length];
                    for (int j = 0; j < sbytes.Length; j++)
                    {
                        byte newByte  = byte.Parse(sbytes[j], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                        b[j]          = newByte;
                    }
```

I like using number styles hex number.